# Usar variables fuera de $sheet->each() - Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, excel

Tengo una función que importa un Excel con la librería Laravel-Excel, y dentro de dicha función en el **$sheet->each(function($row)) {}** voy añadiendo los registros en un array que he declarado dentro de la función pero fuera del $sheet->each(), la cosa es que luego abajo del todo de la función no puedo usar dicho array para hacer un return, es como si no estuviera declarado.

Sabéis si hay algún método o funcionalidad en concreto de Laravel Excel para hacerlo?

```
public function excel($code){
        $i = 0;
        $transact = array();

        $file = File::find($code);
        $url = $file->FILE_url;

            Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($url, function ($sheet) use($i, $transact){

                $hoja->each(function ($row) use($i, $transact){

                        $inCode = $row['inCode'];
                        $prCode = $row['prCode'];

                        $transact[$i] = (int)$inCode;
                        $transact[$i] = (int)$prCode;                        

                        $i++;

                });

                    return $transact;
            });
    }
```

De este modo el **$i** no autoincrementa y tampoco puedo hacer return de **$transact** por mucho que ponga global delante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica en que el closure que estás pasando como parámetro, tiene su propio contexto, donde las variables pasadas mediate `use` son pasadas por valor y no por referencia. Es por esto que no son modificables.

La forma de modificar estas variables es pasarlas por referencia, mediante el modificador `&`:

```
$hoja->each(function ($row) use(&$i, &$transact){
  $inCode = $row['inCode'];
  $prCode = $row['prCode'];

  $transact[$i] = (int)$inCode;
  $transact[$i] = (int)$prCode;                        

  $i++;
});
```

---

Edición:

te dejo un código de ejemplo, para que comprendas un poco mejor los closures:

```
<?php

class Test {
  private $a;

  public function run() {
    $this->a = "antiguo A";
    $b = "antiguo B";
    $c = "antiguo C";

    $fn = function() use($b, &$c) {
      $this->a = "nuevo  A";
      $b = "nuevo  B";
      $c = "nuevo  C";

      echo "modificando en closure: \$a = '{$this->a}' \$b = '$b' \$c = '$c'".PHP_EOL;
    };

    echo "Valor antes del closure: \$a = '{$this->a}' \$b = '$b' \$c = '$c'".PHP_EOL;
    $fn();
    echo "Valor despues del closure: '{$this->a}' \$b = '$b' \$c = '$c'".PHP_EOL;
  }
}


$test = new Test();

$test->run();
```

Output:

```
Valor antes del closure: $a = 'antiguo A' $b = 'antiguo B' $c = 'antiguo C'
modificando en closure: $a = 'nuevo  A' $b = 'nuevo  B' $c = 'nuevo  C'
Valor despues del closure: 'nuevo  A' $b = 'antiguo B' $c = 'nuevo  C'
```

Es importante notar que se hace un vinculación automática de `$this`, por lo que se puede acceder a esta propiedad sin necesidad de indicarlo en el `use` ([leer](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php#example-202))

Te recomiendo leer [Clausuras y ámbitos](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php#example-201).